# Given a .gb file and a locus - how to get relevant annotations in Python?

Tags: sequence-annotation, python

Given a `.gb` file and a specific locus in the genome - how can I parse the relevant annotations in Python (i.e., annotations that include that locus)?

I import the features using:

```
SeqIO.read('my_gb_file.gb', 'gb').features
```

I then wish scan/filter sequence meta data.

Is there a function or method in `Biopython` that does this?

Answer (score 1):

Biopython is the main package for this. It's only a few lines, so it is not reinventing the wheel.

So you want to iterate across the features table (a list in Biopython) of a record and find the case where the qualifier['locus'][0] matches your query.

The things to watch out for are:

- filter by `type` (CDS?)
- entries where there is not key among the qualifiers, so add error catching (try: ... except Exception: pass
- the values of the qualifiers of a feature are a list. so add a [0]
- multithreading.Pool might help if speed is a worry (which it really shouldn't). Asyncio and thread are not the way (both single core).

A nice handy way to do operations on the `features` is to convert it to a pandas dataframe.

```
from Bio.SeqFeature import SeqFeature
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Seq import Seq
import pandas as pd

        def convert(feat: SeqFeature, flatten:bool=True):
    if flatten:
        clean = lambda v: v[0] if isinstance(v, list) else v
        qualifiers = {k: clean(v) for k, v in feat.qualifiers.items()}
    else:
        qualifiers = feat.qualifiers
    return {'id': feat.id,
            'type': feat.type,
            'location_strand': feat.location.strand, 
            'location_start': feat.location.start,
            'location_end': feat.location.end,
            **qualifiers}

transcript = SeqIO.read('.gb', 'genbank')
feats = pd.DataFrame([convert(feat) for feat in transcript.features])
```

This means that in a jupyter notebook one can display the table to look at it (`feats` as last line in a cell or `IPython.display.display(feats)`), export it to a csv (`feats.to_cvs('.csv')`) or subset it:

```
subfeats = feats.loc[(feats['type'] == 'exon') & (feats['location_start']  > 100)& (feats['location_end']  < 500)]
```

Comment: This is not a homework question. A `list` in python comes with the builtin function `index`. It felt to me a bit like implementing `list.index`, so I asked. This seems to me like an extremely common operation, so I thought it is probable that such a function already exists, and I just failed to find it. Thanks anyway for your answer!

Comment: Sorry, I am really bad at figuring out when it's a homework question and when it isn't...

Comment: No harm done. And clearly you did your best to help :)

Comment: I removed my statement about no homework and copypasted a chunk of code to convert it to a pandas dataframe which makes life easier.